# Remember dropdown selection in a jsp file

Tags: html, jsp

I have a dropdown list in a jsp file

```
<select name="PID" id="PID" style="min-width: 100px;" >

<% 
for(somelist pm : List) { %>
<option value="<%=pm.getsmthing()%>" selected><%=pm.getName()%></option>
<option  value="-1">Select a Property</option>
```

This is inside a form. I want to remember the selected item name after submission of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your choosen value to HTTP session and retrive it anytime you need to show your form.

Answer (score 1):

Just print `selected` conditionally whenever the associated request parameter has exactly the same value.

```
<option value="<%=pm.getsmthing()%> <%=(pm.getsmthing().equals(request.getParameter("PID")) ? "selected" : "")%>><%=pm.getName()%></option>
```

Do **not** store it in the session. It would affect *all* pages in all browser tabs/windows in the same session which may result in "wtf?" experiences of the enduser.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, that's pretty an [oldschool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) way of writing JSPs. Learn [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) and [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). Your code would then look like this:

```
<select name="PID" id="PID" style="min-width: 100px;">
  <c:forEach items="${List}" var="pm">
    <option value="${pm.smthing}" ${pm.smthing == param.PID ? 'selected' : ''}>${pm.name}</option>
    <option value="-1">Select a Property</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```